# Difference to previous row in python on a specific group in percentage

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similiar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501074/how-to-calculate-difference-on-previous-within-set-of-grouped-rows-in-a-datafram) and to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347497/pandas-groupby-diff). But the main difference is that I do not have any timestamp column, my data looks the following:

```
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'Year', 'Month']['Sales'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by=(['A','B','Year','Month']))

A    B  Year Month Sales
Der Die 2019  1     2
Der Die 2019  2     3
...
Die Das 2019  1    40
Die Das 2019  2    30
```

How can i get the difference for each group (pair of A and B) to the previous month (in this case previos row), that I get the following output:

```
A    B  Year Month Sales Diff
Der Die 2019  1     2    0
Der Die 2019  2     3    3/2
...
Die Das 2019  1    40  0
Die Das 2019  2    30  30/40
```

Note that in case of missing values, i want to have a 0 in it.

When I use:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['Sales'].diff().fillna()
```

I only get the difference, but not the percentage:

```
A    B  Year Month Sales Diff
Der Die 2019  1     2    0
Der Die 2019  2     3    3-2
...
Die Das 2019  1    40  0
Die Das 2019  2    30  30-40
```

Comment: Do you think `df['diff'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'Year'])['Sales'].diff().fillna(0)` ?

Comment: Its not really a duplicate, i am seraching for the percentage and not the dif

Comment: use `pct_change()` instead of `diff()`